# Django Queries with many2many & 'through'

Tags: python, django, database, filter

I'm quite new to Django and I have some troubles to understand how to fetch data in my database.
I think however that my problem is not so complex : I have music works and instruments. To be performed, **each work need various instruments in a certain quantity**.

Here are my models :

```py
class Instrument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class MusicWork(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    performers = models.ManyToManyField(Instrument, through='MusicWorkInstrument')


class MusicWorkInstrument(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(MusicWork, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    instrument = models.ForeignKey(Instrument, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Now that I have my database structure, I want to perform some queries.
For example, I play the piano and I want to play with my friend who is a violonist.

- *How can I ask for all works composed exactly 1 piano and 1 violin?*

Let's say we didn't find something interesting, so let's try to find some arrangements:

- *How can I get all works with 1 piano and 1 other instrument ?*

We changed our mind, and now we would like to find a new fellow musician:

- *We need to search for all works with 1 piano, 1 violin, and any other instrument except the bassoon (sorry but it doesn't fit with the violin :( )*

I've been trying to figure out how to do these requests for like 3 hours, but as I'm just learning Django, I don't know all the operations on QuerySet and I'm quite confused..

Please, could you help me to find what to play with my friend ? :D

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have only done the first one, but all of them should be similiar. I couldn't do it in straight queries so i had to use some python.

#### data input in database

```
i1 = Instrument.objects.create(name="piano")
i2 = Instrument.objects.create(name="violin")
i3 = Instrument.objects.create(name="drums")
i4 = Instrument.objects.create(name="guitar")
i5 = Instrument.objects.create(name="bassoon")

w1 = MusicWork.objects.create(name="w1") # w1 contains extra instrument
w1.performers.add(i1, through_defaults={'quantity':1})
w1.performers.add(i2, through_defaults={'quantity':1})
w1.performers.add(i3, through_defaults={'quantity':1})

w2 = MusicWork.objects.create(name="w2") # w2 is the required work
w2.performers.add(i1, through_defaults={'quantity':1})
w2.performers.add(i2, through_defaults={'quantity':1})

w3 = MusicWork.objects.create(name="w3") # w3 has wrong quantities
w3.performers.add(i1, through_defaults={'quantity':2})
w3.performers.add(i2, through_defaults={'quantity':1})

MusicWorkInstrument.objects.all()
```

Output of last code line is

```
<QuerySet[
    <MusicWorkInstrument: w1-piano-1>,
    <MusicWorkInstrument: w1-violin-1>,
    <MusicWorkInstrument: w1-drums-1>,
    <MusicWorkInstrument: w2-piano-1>,
    <MusicWorkInstrument: w2-violin-1>,
    <MusicWorkInstrument: w3-piano-2>,
    <MusicWorkInstrument: w3-violin-1>
]>
```

#### getting all works with piano instrument with quantity 1

```
query1 = [i.work for i in MusicWorkInstrument.objects.filter(instrument__name="piano", quantity=1)]
query1
Out: [<MusicWork: w1>, <MusicWork: w2>]
```

#### getting all works with violin instrument with quantity 1

```
query2 = [i.work for i in MusicWorkInstrument.objects.filter(instrument__name="violin", quantity=1)]
query2
Out: [<MusicWork: w1>, <MusicWork: w2>, <MusicWork: w3>]
```

#### getting all the works which contain any other insturment in any quantity

```
excluding_list = [i.name for i in Instrument.objects.exclude(name__in=["piano","violin"])]
excluding_list
Out: ['drums', 'guitar', 'bassoon']

query3 = [ i.work for i in MusicWorkInstrument.objects.filter(instrument__name__in=excluding_list) ]
query3
Out: [<MusicWork: w1>]
```

#### intersection between the first 2 and difference of the 3rd will give the ans

```
query_final = ( set(query1) & set(query2 ) ).difference( set(query3) )
query_final
Out: {<MusicWork: w2>}   # this is a set
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! That's already a big difference with what I had, because I was trying to do it starting from the Work model which is a bit weird.

I'll try to find the other answers alone (but if anyone has an idea feel free to tell me :D )